# How to filter arrays in json based on specific value using jq

Tags: json, bash, equality, jq

I am trying to make a filter using jq to filter the arrays in this json to get only the arrays that have **"policy_id": 199383** and exclude the arrays that contain different policy_id value.

```
{
  "links": {
    "policy_id": 199383,
    "violations": [
      69892478
    ]
  },
  "incident_preference": "PER_CONDITION_AND_TARGET",
  "closed_at": 1519408001909,
  "opened_at": 1519407125437,
  "id": 17821334
}
{
  "links": {
    "policy_id": 199383,
    "violations": [
      69889831
    ]
  },
  "incident_preference": "PER_CONDITION_AND_TARGET",
  "closed_at": 1519408011851,
  "opened_at": 1519406230858,
  "id": 17820349
}
{
  "links": {
    "policy_id": 194774,
    "violations": [
      68446755
    ]
  },
  "incident_preference": "PER_POLICY",
  "closed_at": 1518835775531,
  "opened_at": 1518835745303,
  "id": 17422347
}
{
  "links": {
    "policy_id": 199383,
    "violations": [
      69892488
    ]
  },
  "incident_preference": "PER_CONDITION_AND_TARGET",
  "closed_at": 1519402345676,
  "opened_at": 1519401235467,
  "id": 17821334
}
```

I tried this :
jq '.incidents[] | select (.links.policy_id == "199383")' file.json. But not having anything in return ? Can anyone help.

Thank you

Comment: You're comparing a string against an integer. `.links.policy_id` is `199383`, not `"199383"`.

Comment: Also, given what you've pasted, I'd expect your document to start with `{"incidents": [` and have a `]}` at the end, but it doesn't. Does what you've pasted actually reflect your real data format?

Comment: Thanks for catching that mistake. It works after I removed the "" to compare it with an integer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Also the posted `json` input is not valid because of missing separator after each object.

Comment: @sjsam, ...not valid as a single JSON document, but a stream of documents *is* something jq will accept, so I let that one slide.

Answer (score 2):

```
jq '.incidents[]| select(.links.policy_id==199383)' file.json
```

should do it.

**Output**

```
{
  "links": {
    "policy_id": 199383,
    "violations": [
      69892478
    ]
  },
  "incident_preference": "PER_CONDITION_AND_TARGET",
  "closed_at": 1519408001909,
  "opened_at": 1519407125437,
  "id": 17821334
}
{
  "links": {
    "policy_id": 199383,
    "violations": [
      69889831
    ]
  },
  "incident_preference": "PER_CONDITION_AND_TARGET",
  "closed_at": 1519408011851,
  "opened_at": 1519406230858,
  "id": 17820349
}
{
  "links": {
    "policy_id": 199383,
    "violations": [
      69892488
    ]
  },
  "incident_preference": "PER_CONDITION_AND_TARGET",
  "closed_at": 1519402345676,
  "opened_at": 1519401235467,
  "id": 17821334
}
```

From [json.org](http://json.org/)

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in
>   **double quotes**, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as
>   a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java
>   string.)

and

> A number is very much like a C or Java number, except that the octal
>   and hexadecimal formats are **not** used.

So `199383` is clearly different from `"199383"`. They are number and string respectively.

<sup>**Note :** Emphasis in quoted text are mine.</sup>