# How to filter JSON array using JQ in shell (STRIPE)?

Tags: json, shell, jq

Hello internet people,

Apparently I had the same problem of many but after searching a lot even here I could not find a reasonable answer at all!

**My problem:**

On shell I did enter the command:
`stripe invoices list --customer MY_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE`

Then the following JSON appeared:

```
{
  "object": "list",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "INVOICE_ID",
      "object": "invoice",
      "account_country": "COUNTRY",
      "account_name": "MY_BUSYNESS_NAME",
      "account_tax_ids": null,
      "amount_due": 1000,
      "amount_paid": 1000,
      "amount_remaining": 0,
      "application_fee_amount": null,
      "attempt_count": 1,
      "attempted": true,
      "auto_advance": false,
      "billing_reason": "subscription_create",
      "charge": "CHARGE_ID",
      "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
      "created": SOME_UNIXTIME,
      "currency": "usd",
      "custom_fields": null,
      "customer": "CUSTOMER_ID",
      "customer_address": null,
      "customer_email": "CUSTOMER_EMAIL",
      "customer_name": null,
      "customer_phone": "CUSTOMER_PHONE",
      "customer_shipping": null,
      "customer_tax_exempt": "none",
      "customer_tax_ids": [

      ],
      "default_payment_method": null,
      "default_source": null,
      "default_tax_rates": [

      ],
      "description": null,
      "discount": null,
      "discounts": [

      ],
      "due_date": null,
      "ending_balance": 0,
      "footer": null,
      "hosted_invoice_url": "INVOICE_URL_GOES_HERE",
      "invoice_pdf": "INVOICE_PDF_URL_GOES_HERE",
      "last_finalization_error": null,
      "lines": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "ID",
            "object": "line_item",
            "amount": 1000,
            "currency": "usd",
            "description": "PLAN_DESCRIPTION",
            "discount_amounts": [

            ],
            "discountable": true,
            "discounts": [

            ],
            "livemode": false,
            "metadata": {
            },
            "period": {
              "end": SOME_UNIXTIME,
              "start": SOME_UNIXTIME
            },
            "plan": {
              "id": "PRICE_ID_HERE",
              "object": "plan",
              "active": true,
              "aggregate_usage": null,
              "amount": 1000,
              "amount_decimal": "1000",
              "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
              "created": SOME_UNIXTIME,
              "currency": "usd",
              "interval": "month",
              "interval_count": 1,
              "livemode": false,
              "metadata": {
              },
              "nickname": null,
              "product": "PRODUCT_ID_HERE",
              "tiers_mode": null,
              "transform_usage": null,
              "trial_period_days": null,
              "usage_type": "licensed"
            },
            "price": {
              "id": "MORE_ID_HERE",
              "object": "price",
              "active": true,
              "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
              "created": SOME_UNIXTIME,
              "currency": "usd",
              "livemode": false,
              "lookup_key": null,
              "metadata": {
              },
              "nickname": null,
              "product": "PRODUCT_ID_HERE",
              "recurring": {
                "aggregate_usage": null,
                "interval": "month",
                "interval_count": 1,
                "trial_period_days": null,
                "usage_type": "licensed"
              },
              "tiers_mode": null,
              "transform_quantity": null,
              "type": "recurring",
              "unit_amount": 1000,
              "unit_amount_decimal": "1000"
            },
            "proration": false,
            "quantity": 1,
            "subscription": "SUBSCRIPTION_ID_HERE",
            "subscription_item": "SUBS_ITEM_ID_HERE",
            "tax_amounts": [

            ],
            "tax_rates": [

            ],
            "type": "subscription"
          }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 1,
        "url": "IV_URL_HERE"
      },
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "next_payment_attempt": null,
      "number": "NUMBER_IV_XXXX",
      "on_behalf_of": null,
      "paid": true,
      "payment_intent": "PAYMENT_INTENT_ID_HERE",
      "payment_settings": {
        "payment_method_options": null,
        "payment_method_types": null
      },
      "period_end": SOME_UNIXTIME,
      "period_start": SOME_UNIXTIME,
      "post_payment_credit_notes_amount": 0,
      "pre_payment_credit_notes_amount": 0,
      "receipt_number": null,
      "starting_balance": 0,
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "status": "paid",
      "status_transitions": {
        "finalized_at": SOME_UNIXTIME,
        "marked_uncollectible_at": null,
        "paid_at": SOME_UNIXTIME,
        "voided_at": null
      },
      "subscription": "SUBSCRIPTION_ID_HERE",
      "subtotal": 1000,
      "tax": null,
      "total": 1000,
      "total_discount_amounts": [

      ],
      "total_tax_amounts": [

      ],
      "transfer_data": null,
      "webhooks_delivered_at": SOME_UNIXTIME
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "url": "/some_path"
}
```

I'm able to access the second level with this command:

`stripe invoices list --customer MY_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE | [.id,.attempt_count,.billing_reason,.created,.customer,.customer_email,.lines.data[],.paid,.status]'`

Which returns a nice response, but I do want to filter few values inside data *(data.lines.data[])* like **id**, **plan** and inside plan the **id**, **currency** and **product** for example.

**My question:**

Does any one knows how to do that with this kind of commands?

---

Just in case, those are the questions and answer that I tried but couldn't figured how to do it at all!

[How to filter array of objects by element property values using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121740/how-to-filter-array-of-objects-by-element-property-values-using-jq)

[How to filter arrays in json based on specific value using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956030/how-to-filter-arrays-in-json-based-on-specific-value-using-jq)

[How to filter nested arrays in JSON while maintaining structure using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775875/how-to-filter-nested-arrays-in-json-while-maintaining-structure-using-jq)

[filtering from JSON output from curl using JQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595453/filtering-from-json-output-from-curl-using-jq)

[Filtering JSON by object name using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583568/filtering-json-by-object-name-using-jq)

[How to filter JSON using jq stream (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324497/how-to-filter-json-using-jq-stream)

[How to filter and replace values in json with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58763507/how-to-filter-and-replace-values-in-json-with-jq)

[Filtering JSON list in shell using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50882417/filtering-json-list-in-shell-using-jq)

I did also try a lot attempts on my own, like:

`stripe invoices list --customer MY_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE | [.id,.attempt_count,.billing_reason,.created,.customer,.customer_email,.lines.data[.id.plan[][.id,.plan[.id,.currency,.product]],.paid,.status]'`

**Response:**
jq: error (at :179): Cannot index string with string "plan"

`stripe invoices list --customer MY_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE | [.id,.attempt_count,.billing_reason,.created,.customer,.customer_email,.lines.data[][],.paid,.status]'`

- This one return a null value for the second data content.

**Response:**

```
[
  "DESIRED_ID",
  1,
  "value_retrieved_ok",
  unixtime_ok,
  "SOME_ID_OK",
  "customer_mail@ok.com",
  null, <<< ??? 
  true,
  "paid"
]
```

**EDIT:**

Desired result should look like:

```
[
  "DESIRED_ID",
  1,
  "value_retrieved_ok",
  unixtime_ok,
  "SOME_ID_OK",
  "customer_mail@ok.com",
  "id"             // the id inside lines.data{}
    ["id",         // the id inside lines.data.plan
     "currency",   // the currency inside lines.data.plan
     "product"     // the product inside lines.data.plan
    ]
  true,
  "paid"
]
```

Anyway I do hope that there's a good soul out there have mercy!

Comment: The JSON as updated to the Q is invalid. The literal string `SOME_UNIXTIME` needs to be inside quotes

Comment: What is the _exact_ desired output. Please update it, so that its not left to speculation

Comment: Hello @Inian,
I changed the original values.
The desired result should look like:
[
  "DESIRED_ID",
  1,
  "value_retrieved_ok",
  unixtime_ok,
  "SOME_ID_OK",
  "customer_mail@ok.com",
  "id"[ 
    "plan_id",
    "currency",
    "product"
  ]
  true,
  "paid"
]

But I do not know how to access the third sublevel level or lower with shell command line.

Comment: The problem isn't the JSON! The problem is **how can I filter it with JQ in sub-levels beyond the second**.
To work with a short response, because I don't need all those fields.

Comment: @luciela - Have you read the [mcve] guidelines?

Comment: Hi @peak,
Yes! And this is the best I can do.

Comment: @luciela - Great, but it's clear you could easily do better, both with respect to the "m" (minimal) part, and with respect to the "r" (reproducible) part.  In this case, especially, the JSON should be valid, and the expected output should agree exactly with the illustrative input.

Comment: Sry @peak I didn't meant to be rude or disrespect any rule here.
And by the way thank you for your answer was exactly what needed! Now I know how to access even deeper levels following this pattern.
Thanks for the help and advice! I'll do better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are a bit difficult to follow, especially since the "expected output" does not correspond exactly to the given input, but the following is either what you're looking for, or very close to it:

```
.data[]
| [.id,.attempt_count,.billing_reason,.created,.customer,.customer_email]
  + (.lines.data[] | [.id, [.plan.id, .plan.currency, .plan.product]])
  + [.paid,.status]
```